# Understanding the Google specification for crawlable ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using dotnet c#, and jQuery plus webservices for ajax calls. My paginations works like twitter and facebook paginations. In the onload event, a ajax call fill a content area with 10 rows, and a click or a roll the page down event call the same ajax call, with a page parameter, that brings more 10 rows, and so on. I dont have a canonical pagination for non javascript users. I read the Google specification about crawlable ajax, but Im not sure how to convert my model to the google new model.

First of all, I use jQuery ajax post, using json format. So its possible to create a aspx page that read a URL like `http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?_escaped_fragment_=somevalue` and use the _escaped_fragment_ value to return content. But, somehow I have to propagate this page link to the google crawler `http://www.domain.com/search.aspx#!somevalue`. Is this ok?

Ok! But when the Google Crawler access my paginations, the crawler will not see any link to http://www.domain.com/search.aspx#!1, unless I point it in the sitemap, and it makes no sense to me. Im in a big mess. Can someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try:

Consider a link to a page, like `www.domain.com/search.aspx?query=google#1`.

The page search.aspx must have a function that reads the hash, and get content relative to the page 1. Part of this content is `www.domain.com/search.aspx?query=google#2`. The function do the same, but now it gets content relative to page 2. And so on.

Now I have to exchange the #1 and #2 to #!1 and #!2. My logic goes the same, but google crawler will call `www.domain.com/search.aspx?query=google&_escaped_fragment_=1`, and I will have to create a url route that redirect this url to some page that will return a html snap shot for the result.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the diagram here: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

is that google will change your *existing* "pretty" url (e.g. http://www.domain.com/search.aspx?page=2) to an ugly version (including #!).  It does this by normal mechanisms - finding that link on your page somewhere (e.g. an href to  "page 2").

Then it submits it, your site must understand that, and render the snapshot.

So no need for sitemap unless you don't have the page 2 link (which links to page 3, etc. )